# What is an example of an oriented simplicial complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, intuition, simplicial-complex

From Rotman's Algebraic Topology:

> An oriented simplicial complex $K$ is a simplicial complex and a
>   partial order on $\text{Vert}(K)$ whose restriction to the vertices of any simplex in $K$ is a linear order.

I don't understand how I would come up with an example for this.

If you took $K=\{\Delta^3, \Delta^2, \Delta^1, \Delta^0, \text{all faces of simplexes}: \Delta^i \cap \Delta^j = \emptyset, \text{ for $i,j \in \{0,1,2,3\}$} \}$.

How could you define a partial ordering on $\text{Vert(K)}$?  And how would you define a linear order for any restriction to a simplex?

Comment: I don't understand your notation: is $K$ supposed to be the disjoint union of a 3-simplex, a 2-simplex, a 1-simplex, and a 0-simplex? If so, first put linear orders on the vertices of each of those four simplices; each of those four linear orders will then restrict to a linear order of each subset. Then extend to a partial order on the disjoint union of their vertex sets by declaring that a vertex in $\Delta^i$ and a vertex in $\Delta^j$ are incomparable if $i \ne j$.